# Intersection of two lines using Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the intersection of two lines, if the first line passes through $(0,0)$, $(2,2)$ and the second line pass through points $(3,4)$ and $(1,2)$. I'd prefer the solution uses Cramer's rule, since that's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

If two lines intersect, you know that for some scalars $s$ and $t$,
$$(1-t)(0,0) + t(2,2) = (1-s)(3,4) + s(1,2).$$

Now can you refactor the above into a system of two equations in two unknowns, on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Cramer's rules for that: the two lines do not intersect since they have the same slope:
$$\frac22=\frac{4-2}{3-1}$$
and are distinct since the line through $(3,4)$ and $(1;2)$ does not pass through the origin.

*General solution*:

To find the intersection of two lines defined by two points $(a_0, b_0), ~(a_1,b_1)$ and $(c_0,d_0),~(c_1,d_1)$ respectively, the simplest is to use the determinantal form of the equations of these two lines: 
$$\begin{vmatrix}a_0&a_1&x\\
b_0&b_1&y\\
1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0, \qquad \begin{vmatrix}c_0&c_1&x\\
d_0&d_1&y\\
1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0,$$
so one has to determine the solution of these two linear equations if any.

Comment: In the second part of the answer, wut happens after i use the determinental form of the equations?

Comment: The first equation yields $x=y$, and plugging this relation in the second equation, you obtain the equation $\;1=0$, so there's no solution.